# How to Filter text from a set in Python

Tags: python, string, list, filter, set

I am running through text and I want to save the items that do not contain certain text.

The text consists of single words, and multiple words.

so far i have:

```
def check_data(text):
    filter_words = ['subscribe','entertaining']
    filter_bigrams = [{'free', 'ticket'}, {'current', 'price'}]


   for filter in filter_words:
       if filter in text:
           return(0)

   for filter in filter_bigrams:
       if filter in text:
           return(0)

   return(1)

mytext = 'free xubscribes tickets now'
found = check_data(mytext)
print(found)
```

and the error i get it:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not set
```

In the above filter bigrams does not work. Please help?

Thanks

Comment: error here: `if filter in text:`, filter is set, not string

Comment: You need to traverse on all elements of sets in your second for loop

Comment: The core thing is that you're trying to see if a set is in a string. `{'foo', 'bar'} in 'some string'` for example is not valid. Why not just make the bigrams like `filter_bigrams = ['free ticket', 'current price']` ? Or are you trying to filter if those words `free` and `ticket` appear *anywhere* in the text, not necessarily together?

Comment: What is the mean of multiple words, how do you want to compare them as a whole or individual words? You should be little more elaborative about your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution. You don't have to iterate over `filter_words` to check if `text` is one of the member of `filter_words`. However you have to iterate over `filter_bigrams` since it is the list of set. Note that this solution will only result first match.

```
import re

def check_data(text):
    all_words = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', text)
    filter_words = ['subscribe','entertaining']
    filter_bigrams = [{'free', 'ticket'}, {'current', 'price'}]

   for word in all_words
       if word in filter_words:
          return(0)


       for filter in filter_bigrams:
           if word in filter:
              return(0)

   return(1)

mytext = 'free xubscribes tickets now'
found = check_data(mytext)
print(found)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume for bigrams you are just interested if both words is in "text" or not, and not concerned with their order.

This will work:-

```
import re

def check_data(text):
    all_words = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', text)
    filter_words = ['subscribe', 'entertaining']
    filter_bigrams = [['free','tickets'],['current', 'price']
    ]

    for word in all_words:
        if word in filter_words:
            return(0)


    for filter_list in filter_bigrams:
        if (filter_list[0] in all_words and filter_list[1] in all_words):
            return(0)


    return(1)
```

**Note:- In filter biagrams i have changed ticket to tickets, otherwise it won't work for "mytext"**

Comment: Fix your indentation.